# C# webbrowser alters source

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control which I navigate to an URL that contains this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body marginheight="60" topmargin="60">
    <p align="center"><img src="nocontent.jpg" alt="" height="434" width="525" border="0" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I use this code to fetch the source:

```
HTMLDocument objHtmlDoc = (HTMLDocument)browser.Document.DomDocument;
string pageSource = objHtmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
Console.WriteLine(pageSource);
```

This is the result:

```
<HEAD><TITLE></TITLE>
<META content=text/html;charset=utf-8 http-equiv=content-type></HEAD>
<BODY topMargin=60 marginheight="60">
<P align=center><IMG border=0 alt="" src="nocontent.jpg" width=525 height=434></P></BODY>
```

This is no good for further processing, how can I make sure it shows the same source as when I would rightclick it and select "view source"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `browser.DocumentText` to obtain the source HTML.

Using the `HTMLDocument` class will cause it to generate HTML from the conceptual model of the document rather than displaying the original source.